Font Rendering Issue in Visual Studio Code on CachyOS (Arch Linux family)
Why do I have such large gaps in the Visual Studio Code terminal? I uninstalled it, reinstalled it, and it’s the same. I also tried Code - OSS, and the problem persisted. Is it a bug in the software, or did I mess something up in the system?" The fact is, I did change the system font, but everything else in the system is fine, just not in this program.
Bug image

You have large gaps because a terminal requires a fixed-width font. Terminals are strictly grid-shaped; each line is a specific number of columns and each column is exactly the same width.
When you use a variable-width font (with narrow i and wide m and so on), the grid is adjusted to fit the widest character (usually 'm'), and that of course leaves gaps around any characters that are narrower; whereas monospace or fixed-width fonts are designed to fit the grid nicely.
VSCode has a separate setting for the terminal font – set terminal.integrated.fontFamily to monospace or similar. (Then use programmingfonts.org to find some alternative monospace font that fits your style.)

I set 'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace everywhere in Visual Studio Code, and it still doesn't fix the problem :/

"I used the Consolas font, which fixed everything. Thank you for your help. Have a great day! :)
